# preg_replace_callback(): Unknown modifier '/'

Tags: php

I need search and highlight the word.

My sentence is

```
Please see our Author Guide for more information: http://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/author-guide.
you will be contacted shortly asking you to take a decision and sign either a copyright or Open Access licence form.
```

My code

```
function find_highlight_word($word) {
        $text = preg_replace_callback($word, function($matches) use (&$counter) {

            $counter++;
            return '<b class="search_mark highlighted" id="matched_' . $counter . '">'
                    . substr($matches[0], 0, strlen($matches[0]))
                    . '</b>';
        }, $text);

        return $text;
}
$word = '//';
$word = '/' . preg_quote($word) . '/i';
$this->find_highlight_word($word);
```

When I'm searching with '**//**' that time showing php error.

Comment: Well, your function accepts the parameter `$word`, but you seem to use `$string` instead.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes I updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correctly attempting to preg-quote your string, but you're not telling it what your delimiter is, so the `//` inside the string is causing issues. Pass the used delimiter as the second argument, so it can be escaped as well:

```
$word = '/' . preg_quote($string, '/') . '/i';
```